# Mapping affiliations to adjacency matrix output

Tags: r, neural-network, igraph, graph-theory, adjacency-matrix

Let's say I'm using [this affiliation matrix](https://dshizuka.github.io/networkanalysis/02_dataformats.html):

```
library(igraph)

A=c(1,1,0,0) 
B=c(1,0,1,0) 
C=c(1,0,1,0) 
D=c(0,1,0,1) 
E=c(0,0,1,1) 
aff=matrix(c(A,B,C,D,E),nrow=5,byrow=TRUE) 
dimnames(aff)=list(c("A","B","C","D","E"),c("Group1","Group2","Group3","Group4"))
```

Which looks like this:

```
##   Group1 Group2 Group3 Group4
## A      1      1      0      0
## B      1      0      1      0
## C      1      0      1      0
## D      0      1      0      1
## E      0      0      1      1
```

From which you can produce (using `aff %*% t(aff)`) the following adjacency matrix:

```
##   A B C D E
## A 2 1 1 1 0
## B 1 2 2 0 1
## C 1 2 2 0 1
## D 1 0 0 2 1
## E 0 1 1 1 2
```

The groups (e.g. `Group1`, `Group2`, etc.) are not preserved in the transformation to an adjacency matrix, thus when plotting:

```
m2=aff %*% t(aff)
g2=graph_from_adjacency_matrix(m2, "undirected", weighted=T, diag=F)
plot(g2, edge.width=E(g2)$weight)
```

[image]

There is no way to know what shared group connection exists between `A` and `B`, `A` and `C`, etc.

**My question**: Is there some way to preserve this grouping variable so that the plot could be made from the adjacency matrix while allowing the edges to be labelled as `Group3` or `Group1` like so?:

[image]

Note: I'm planning to use `visNetwork`, not `igraph`, but this question seems to stem from the data structure itself rather than the package used, so I've chosen this for simplicity's sake.

Comment: Well you will sometimes need more tan one edge for that. For example, nodes B & C share are in _two_ groups together. Do you want one edge with two labels or two edges?

Comment: Good question - I want to preserve the edges as they are, so I'd be looking for two labels on the B/C connection. I'll update my post.

Comment: not answering your question but as an alt, you could plot it as a bipartite graph; `g = graph_from_incidence_matrix(aff) ; plot(g, layout=layout_as_bipartite(g))` . Perhaps add a colour based on the group to assist in the affiliation . `cols = c("Group1"="red", "Group2"="blue", "Group3"="green", "Group4"="orange"); E(g)$color = cols[as_edgelist(g)[,2]]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
m3 = get.edgelist(g2)
lbls = sapply(1:NROW(m3), function(i){
    toString(names(which(aff[m3[i, 1],] == 1 & aff[m3[i, 2],] == 1)))
})
plot(g2, edge.label = lbls)
```

Comment: This is very nearly what I'm looking for! However, for the two connections between nodes B and C, the output of `lbls` concatenates `Group1` and `Group3` into a single label (delimited by a comma). What I need is to have these two labels as separate values, each attributed to their respective edge. This way, if the plot clearly showed the two distinct edges between B and C, both edges would have their correct label (and this vector could then be used for edge color mapping, etc.). Can your answer be modified to reflect this?

Comment: For those interested in my comment above, changing the `g2` call to `g2=graph_from_adjacency_matrix(m2, "undirected", weighted=NULL, diag=F)` with the `weighted=NULL` argument produces an edgelist with the correct number of rows. I've posted a separate question about merging the duplicate values [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58329390/merge-duplicate-characters-in-r-while-preserving-data-frame-structure).